# SSRS report deployments

Tags: sql-server, reporting-services, deployment, rdl, rs.exe

I would appreciate some help or advice on this subject...
So deploying reports to other SSRS sites. Not on the same domain and firewall (but I can remote into the server and work from remote session).

- 100's of reports (so not reasonable to use the report manager to upload the reports and configure the data sources manually)
- RS.EXE works Great!... But I cannot use it because I cannot reach the server from outside the internal network because of firewall restraints.
- Downloading and installing DataTools, load the solution and try to deploy  mostly had issuses, problems have been incorrect versions of the project / SQL version

The SQL server and VS versions the reports were developed on are 2017.
Targeted SQL Server versions would be 2012 or greater.

Somebody must have had this issue and found a solution. I'm looking for any help or advice. I may have overlook something simple. Thanks.

Comment: I can't imagine that using the Deploy functionality within Visual Studio is going to be that problematic. Plus, if you are using a Shared Data Source then you won't have many Data Sources to configure; unless you have 100's of databases, and then that's a different problem.

Comment: There are only a few shared data sources, but if you upload the rdl's manually they lose what data sources they're suppose to use. Anyway VS installation etc. doesn't always work and is not a good solution. I believe RS.exe is the way to go. Is there an rs.exe vb script out there I could use to grab locally copied rdl files to deploy, that would work great!

Comment: No they don't. if you deploy a project via Visual Studio the Shared Data Sources go too, and so do the relationships. VS installation "doesn't work"? From experience I would say that using the SSDT deployment method is definitely the way to go.

Comment: I agree with @Lamu. VS is the way I would do this, just make sure the project properties match the target SSRS version.

Comment: Once again!, I never once said the shared reports referring to the data sources do not go with the report when deploying via SSTD or VS. IMHO what a stupid way to deploy reports via installing SSTD or VS on the server (which has problems sometimes) just to deploy some reports to SSRS. Really there's not a better way? I'm sure some smarter person out there has done this. Seriously.

Answer (score 0):

I tried this GUI tool, which I found in any SSRS forum:
[ReportSync](https://code.google.com/archive/p/reportsync/)

(Works with the SSRS web service asmx)

You can download the source, compile and run. Obviously is not perfect, but is useful to:

1. Clone a SSRS folder (and all the rdl inside) in the same or different SSRS server
2. Download entire SSRS reports struct (rld and rds)
3. Upload entire SSRS reports struct from your local drive

Hope this helps.